# How to fade backdrop when a modal box is opened?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am opening a modal on click and when i opened it, whole screen is applied with a class

```
.modal-backdrop
```

So to display the modal box, I just removed this class on opening modal box in my function as follows,

```
 addnewrecord() {
        $('#editmodel').modal('show');
         setTimeout(function(){ $('.modal-backdrop').remove(); }, 150);
     }
```

As a result ,when i open modal box, background is not getting faded but when a modal box is open background must be fade. So, my question is how to fade background on opening modal box.Can anyone help please.Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to remove `.modal-backdrop`. It is responsible for fading out the background

Comment: Hi Saurav ,actully i am using the model in a tab and when i click on model that class is getting appllied to model box also....that y i removed it.

Comment: Can you please post the example fiddle (code) for this?